# NSPredicate of special characters - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, special-characters, nspredicate

I'm trying to make a predicate that includes special characters

For example:

```
[[myIngredients filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", [alphabet objectAtIndex:idx]]];
```

Here I will get all the ingredient which starts with (let say for idx = 5) 'e'. As I have to do my app in english and french, some ingredients start with special character like 'é' or even 'œ' for 'o'. How can I include these special characters in my predicate?

Best

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the “diacritic insensitive” flag that NSPredicate supports. It’s just like the “c” flag you’re already using, except you use a “d”. Like so:

```
… predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", …
```

Now the string “e” will also match “é”, “ê”, “ë”, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm... except for the œ! Do you have any nice solution for this one? Otherwise, I'll add an exception.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using a compound predicate. Create one NSPredicate to match “o” and another to match “œ”. Then join them together with: `[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1, p2, nil]]`.

Comment: how can one get NDDiacriticInsensitive and NSCaseInsensitive to work together? seems I can only pick one or the other? thanks

Comment: edit: the way we got case insensitive to work with diacritic insensitive was to lowercase the strings involved first, then just use NSDiacriticInsensitive. may not work for everyone's specific cases